# Contrasts can be applied to factors with 2 or more levels error in lm

Tags: r

When I run the two statements below in R to regress a against b and c, I get the error that I have pasted right below. All of the predictors have more than 2 levels. I am not sure what is wrong. Can somebody help?

```
d<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9))
 lmmod <- lm(colnames(d)[1] ~  paste(colnames(d)[2:length(colnames(d))], collapse = "+") , data = d[1:(nrow(d)),])


Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Why the downvote? At least give a reason so that I can fix the problem.

Comment: Do you need `lm(a~b+c, d)` ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to hard-code in the real example. This is just a toy example meant to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reformulate`

```
lm(reformulate(paste0(names(d)[-1], collapse = "+"), names(d)[1]), d)
```

Or using `paste0`

```
lm(paste0(names(d[1]),"~", paste0(names(d)[-1], collapse = "+")), d)
```

Comment: If you are going to pass string as formula, it should be part of one string. In your attempt, they are not. You could have tried something like `lm(paste0(colnames(d)[1], '~' ,paste(colnames(d)[2:length(colnames(d))], collapse = "+")), d)` which is similar to 2nd option I have posted.